# Javascript Clicks, Taps and Hovers

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is:

On desktop: 1) Hover to bring up overlay 2) Click to activate

On touch: 1) Tap to bring up overlay 2) Tap again to activate

What I've come up with so far is the below. However when using a touch device it fires the both `touchend` event and then the `click` event, this causes the overlay click event to be fired unnecessarily. What's the best way around this, if any?

```js
$(".container > .item").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  console.log("hover: " + e.type);
});

$(".container > .item > .overlay").on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
  console.log("click: " + e.type);
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  
  position: relative;
}
  
.item.hover > .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: aboslute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the below, which works rather nicely -- And when changing between touch/pen and mouse.

In effect, for mouse navigation, `mouseover` 'wakes up' the element, and readies the listeners, then `click` gets handled by the listeners. For touch navigation, the first tap 'wakes up' the element, and the second tap gets handled by the listeners.

```js
var hoverCapture = (function() {
  var TOUCH_STATE = {
    'initial': 0,
    'over': 1,
    'click': 2
  };
  
  var eventTargetDefault = '.hover-layer';
  
  function hoverCapture(selectorScope, eventTarget) {
    var eventTarget = typeof eventTarget !== 'undefined' ?  eventTarget : eventTargetDefault;
    
    var $eventTarget = $(selectorScope).find(eventTarget);
    
    var touchState = TOUCH_STATE.initial;
    var previousEventType = '';
    
    $eventTarget.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
      $(this).addClass("hover");
      
      previousEventType = e.type;
    });

    $eventTarget.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass("hover");
      // Order of events is:
      //
      // outside -> .image
      //  touchend, mousenter
      //
      // .image -> .image
      //  touchend, mouseleave, mouseenter
      //
      // .image -> outside
      //  mouseleave
      //
      // When tapping out, we don't receive a touchend
      //  event, since the touchend happens outside of
      //  our scoped listeners
      if (previousEventType === 'touchend') {
        touchState = TOUCH_STATE.over;
      } else {
        touchState = TOUCH_STATE.initial;
      }

      previousEventType = e.type;
    });

    $eventTarget.on('touchend', function(e) {
      if (touchState === TOUCH_STATE.initial) {
        touchState = TOUCH_STATE.over;
      } else {
        touchState = TOUCH_STATE.click;
      }

      previousEventType = e.type;
    });


    $eventTarget.each(function() {
      this.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if (touchState === TOUCH_STATE.over) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }

        previousEventType = e.type;
      }, true);
    });
  }
  
  return hoverCapture;
}());


hoverCapture("#gallery1", ".image");
hoverCapture("#gallery2", ".image");

$(".test").on("click", function(e) {
  alert("Ouch!");
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  margin: 0 -4px -4px 0;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.image .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.image.hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.test {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery" id="gallery1">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="gallery" id="gallery2">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any additions/suggestions *please* do follow up.. This has been giving me headaches for days now!